# SQL Update across Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a Linked Server set up on my host Server: "MyLinkedServer"
I have an SP on my server "HostServer".

I am calling a stored proc on HostServer that updates a table in DatabaseA on MyLinkedServer with values from a table in DatabaseB on MyLinkedServer.

I have other SPs that run fine in the same scenario, but they are doing inserts and deletes, however this SP fails to update the table in DatabaseA (no error returned, just no changed data), and if I change connections to actually run the SP on "MyLinkedServer" it works without a problem.

```
UPDATE MyLinkedServer.DataBaseA.dbo.MyTable
SET Column1 = db2.Column1

FROM MyLinkedServer.DataBaseA.dbo.MyTable db1
INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 Column1 
            FROM MyLinkedServer.DataBaseB.dbo.MyTable db2
            WHERE db2.Id = 2
        ) AS db2 ON db2.Id = 2

WHERE db1.Id = 1
```

Comment: Can you post some sample code?  Also is this SQL Server and if so what version?

Comment: Are you using any distributed transactions?

Comment: No distributed transactions, they fell over as it wasn't set up to handle them on the Linked Server

Comment: Are the other SP's that work fine do Update Data as well not just select?

Comment: The other SPs are doing inserts and deletes, but not updates.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that you're not really joining the two tables since the "ON" clause of the join only refers to db2? So this is basically a multiplication by (only) 1 (row), not a join.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need to reference the alias you reference in the from statement.   Does changing

```
UPDATE MyLinkedServer.DataBaseA.dbo.MyTable
```

into

```
UPDATE db2
```

fix your issue?